# How can I check to see if a program has run? If it has I want to exit the program. I am working in AppleScript.

Tags: applescript

Basically I am making a program for work that logs me in to everything that I need to be in. Currently it is set to run when the computer starts and it does and works just fine. What I don't want to happen though is run again if I restart the computer with in the same day or even better run but skip certain code. Like if run today goto line x. Obviously I'm a bit of a newb but I catch on quick if anybody has any ideas that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to save the AppleScript as an application. Then, store the last time the script ran in a property. Property values are saved between runtimes.

Then, on run, check the property value to see if it contains the current day or some day in the past.

Here’s an example:

```
property lastRun : date "Saturday, January 1, 2000 at 12:00:00 AM"

on run
    tell (current date) to set today to it - (its time)
    if lastRun = today then
        display dialog "Already ran today."
    else if lastRun > today then
        display dialog "I seem to think that I ran in the future. Check your dates."
    else
        --do something
        display dialog "First time today!"
        copy today to lastRun
    end if
end run
```

This stores the current date (technically: the current timestamp reduced by the current time, which should always be the beginning of the day) in the *today* variable. Then, it checks the *today* variable against the *lastRun* property. There is then a condition for if it has run today, if it somehow ran in the future (indicating a date issue with the computer), and if it ran sometime previous to today. In the latter condition, it resets *lastRun* to be *today*.

Note that while properties are saved between runtimes for applications, every time you edit the script and resave it, the property is reset to the hard-coded value given in the script.